# i think my flutter listbuilder is not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm currently making a Flutter app and can't get any further. I have the following problem: I fetch data for the listbuilder from a database and pick it up with flutter via http, this works but then the code runs until it reaches the listbuilder. I will attach the method to get the data and the futurebuilder with the included listbuilder. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

Future-/Listbuilder:

```
FutureBuilder<List>(
                              future: getArticlesByAmount(3),
                              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
                                if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                }else if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
                                  if(snapshot.hasError||!snapshot.hasData){
                                    return AlertDialog(
                                      content: Text("Fehler beim Laden!")
                                    );
                                  }else{
                                    return ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: 3,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        print(snapshot.hasData);
                                        print(snapshot.data);
                                        print(snapshot.data!.first);
                                        print(snapshot.data.toString());
                                        return Text(snapshot.data!.toList()[index]);
                                      },
                                  );
                                 }
                                }else{
                                  print("4");
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                      content: Text("fehler beim laden")
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            ),
```

the method to get data

```
Future<List> getArticlesByAmount(int amount)async {
    print("1");
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.241:25111/api/articles/get/cards/amount/$amount'));
    print("2");
    List cards = new List.empty(growable: true);
    print(json.decode(response.body)["CARD_1"]["DESCR"]);
    for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      print("CARD_$i");
      cards.add(ItemCard(
        thumb: FadeInImage(
          placeholder: AssetImage("assets/images/itemCardLoading.png"),
          image: NetworkImage(
              "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g6jROgo0L.png"),
        ),
        desc: json.decode(response.body)["CARD_$i"]["DESCR"],
        distance: "5KM",
        plz: 27446,
        id: 2,
      )
      );
    }
    return cards;
  }
```

whole class

```
void main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int _currentIndex = 0;
  late PageController _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext mycontext) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: SizedBox.expand(
            child: PageView(
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                setState(() => _currentIndex = index);
              },
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"),  height: 100, width: 400, alignment: Alignment.topCenter),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: 'Suchen...',
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                  suffixIcon: Transform(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    transform: Matrix4.rotationX(math.pi*2),
                                    child:Transform.rotate(
                                        angle:  270 *math.pi /180,
                                        child: IconButton(
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(207, 95, 47, 1),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            _showAlertDialog();// daten aus dialog in hashmap und preferences
                                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                                          },
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.bar_chart_rounded),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ),
                            ),
                            FutureBuilder<List>(
                              future: getArticlesByAmount(3),
                              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
                                if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                }else if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done){
                                  if(snapshot.hasError||!snapshot.hasData){
                                    return AlertDialog(
                                      content: Text("Fehler beim Laden!")
                                    );
                                  }else{
                                    return ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: 3,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return Text("hi!");
                                      },
                                  );
                                 }
                                }else{
                                  print("4");
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                      content: Text("fehler beim laden")
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"),  height: 100, width: 400, alignment: Alignment.topCenter),
                          ]
                      )
                  ),
                ),
                Container(color: Colors.green,),
                Container(
                  child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/logo.png"),  height: 100, width: 400, alignment: Alignment.topCenter),

                          ]
                      )
                  ),
                ),
                Container(color: Colors.black,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Navbar(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0),
            selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
            onItemSelected: (index) {
              setState(() => _currentIndex = index);
              _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
            },
            items: <BottomNavyBarItem>[
              BottomNavyBarItem(
                title: Text('Startseite', style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Noto Sans CJK SC"
                ),),
                icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 30),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Color.fromRGBO(150, 150, 150, 1),
              ),
              BottomNavyBarItem(
                title: Text("Mails"),
                icon: Icon(Icons.chat, size: 30),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Color.fromRGBO(150, 150, 150, 1),
              ),
              BottomNavyBarItem(
                title: Text('Hinzufügen'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle, size: 30),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Color.fromRGBO(150, 150, 150, 1),
              ),
              BottomNavyBarItem(
                title: Text('Merkliste'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_rounded, size: 30),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Color.fromRGBO(150, 150, 150, 1),
              ),
              BottomNavyBarItem(
                title: Text('Profil'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 30),
                activeColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveColor: Color.fromRGBO(150, 150, 150, 1),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void _showAlertDialog(){
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return AlertDialog(
            content: Text("HALLO!"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  Future<List> getArticlesByAmount(int amount)async {
    print("1");
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.241:25111/api/articles/get/cards/amount/$amount'));
    print("2");
    List cards = new List.empty(growable: true);
    print(json.decode(response.body)["CARD_1"]["DESCR"]);
    for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
      print("CARD_$i");
      cards.add(ItemCard(
        thumb: FadeInImage(
          placeholder: AssetImage("assets/images/itemCardLoading.png"),
          image: NetworkImage(
              "https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41g6jROgo0L.png"),
        ),
        desc: json.decode(response.body)["CARD_$i"]["DESCR"],
        distance: "5KM",
        plz: 27446,
        id: 2,
      )
      );
    }
    print(cards[0].toString());
    return cards;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of your print statements ?

Comment: that's it all print statements go up to the listbulder but from then on nothing comes up, not even an error

Comment: Did you try to hard restart (not hot restart by crtl+s) ? could you print the content of```cards``` before ```return cards;``` ?

Comment: i even restarted my whole computer give me a moment.

Comment: if I print the list cards, three itemCard objects come as intended: 2021-08-03 22: 04: 26.132245 + 0200 Runner [4844: 104795] flutter: [ItemCard, ItemCard, ItemCard].

Comment: @highling Instead of `Text(snapshot.data!.toList()[index])` just hard code some value and check whether it's being displayed or not `Text('Test Data')`

Comment: Nothing. there is nothing on the display or in the console. As I said, from the beginning of the listbuilder, no more code is executed and I have no idea why.

Comment: Can you add your complete build function? Are you adding it in a column ? If you replace that listview builder with a container or text, is that being displayed?

Comment: i edited the question. the itemcard class works as far as I've already hard coded a few

Comment: Either you've to specify a height for your listview or it's parent container. In your view structure, you are not specifying the height anywhere. You've a scrollview, inside that a column and inside that a listview etc. All these doesn't have a specific height constraint.

Comment: so best I should give a height everywhere?

Comment: @highling You need to ask yourself, why you need a scroll view there and why you need that column, also whether it's possible to restructure the layout without those. Only you know the UI requirement. Also check about the expand widget and flex property

Comment: okay thank you i will try the sizes etc i hope it works.